# carrierwave not recognizing keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I just pulled an older version of a project I'm working on in rails from github and am having problems with carrierwave for image upload. I used the figaro gem to store my secret keys so they were not in the file I pulled down (figaro puts an application.yml file that then gets listed in .gitignor). So I added the figaro configuration, but carrierwave still refuses to work. I even tried putting the keys into the carrierwave configuration directly to see if it was something with figaro, but no luck.

My config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                      
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_KEY_ID'],                      
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],                        
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',                 
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucketname'                    
  config.fog_public     = true                                   
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

I am pretty sure that my keys are being stored properly in my development environment, but I have no idea why carrierwave is not working like it did before.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some log output showing what happens when you try to use CarrierWave?

Comment: @sackopotatoes can you provide us the o/p of following command `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.fog_credentials`

Comment: @Viren when I run that command it shows the access keys as being there